# Configure chrony ntp server on rhel8:error timeout

Tags: linux, chrony

I have configured the `chrony` NTP server on rhel8 by using the commands `chronyc sources -v` and `chronyc tracking` to verify the time synchronization and it has succeeded. However, when I use the command `w32tm /monitor /computers:XX.X.XX.XXX` from Win10 to verify it, it gives me the following error `ICMP: 0ms delay NTP: Error ERROR_TIMEOUT-No response from server within 1000 ms`.

vi /etc/chrony.conf
server XXX.XX.XX.220 iburst
server XXX.XX.XX.219 iburst
server XXX.XX.XX.218 iburst
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift
makestep 0.2 5
#rtcsync
#hwtimestamp *
#minsources 2

## Allow NTP client access from local network.

#allow 192.168.0.0/16
allow XXX.XX.XX.0/24
#local stratum 10
#keyfile /etc/chrony.keys
leapsectz right/UTC
logdir /var/log/chrony
log measurements statistics tracking
leapsecmode slew
maxslewrate 1000
smoothtime 400 0.001 leaponly
bindaddress 127.0.0.1
logchange 0.5

## but when I use the following command to check it,it can not get the clients information.
[root@test etc]# chronyc clients
Hostname                      NTP   Drop Int IntL Last     Cmd   Drop Int  Last

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Per default chrony does not work as a server who can be used by everyone. You have to configure who is allowed to use your chrony.

vi /etc/chrony.conf

```
# Allow NTP client access from local network.
#allow 192.168/16
allow XX.X.XX.XXX/32
```

Comment: I have configured the ntp client :[allow XX.X.XX.XXX/32],how do i verfy ntp client can access to my chrony server.

Comment: Restart the chronyd and give it a try.

Comment: I have tried it ,but it still failed.

Comment: Have you checked the firewall, selinux?

Comment: yes, I checked it and the results is following:
[root@test ~]# systemctl is-enabled firewalld
disabled
[root@test ~]# systemctl status firewalld
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled; vendor >
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:firewalld(1)

[1]+  停止                  systemctl status firewalld
[root@test ~]# getenforce
Disabled

Answer (score 0):

I know its old but you actually need on the server to:

```
# tell chrony to serve time
local
# allow all clients to pull time
allow 0.0.0.0/0
```

Make sure you also dont have some firewalld or something that can block the traffic